# How to "translate" array to label?

Tags: arrays, numpy, label, predict, one-hot-encoding

After predicting a certain image I got the following classes:

```
np.argmax(classes, axis=2)
array([[ 1, 10, 27,  8,  2,  6,  6]])
```

I now want to translate the classes to the corresponding letters numbers. To onehot encode my classes before I used this code (in order to see which class stands for which letter/number:

```
def my_onehot_encoded(label):
    # define universe of possible input values
    characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    # define a mapping of chars to integers
    char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(characters))
    int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(characters))
    # integer encode input data
    integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in label]
    # one hot encode
    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in integer_encoded:
        character = [0 for _ in range(len(characters))]
        character[value] = 1
        onehot_encoded.append(character)

    return onehot_encoded
```

That means: class `1` is equal to number `1`, class `10` to `A` and so on. How can I invert this and get the array to a new label?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the problem, but this might work?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 1, 10, 27,  8,  2,  6,  6]])
characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
np.array(list(characters))[a]
```

output:

```
array([['1', 'A', 'S', '8', '2', '6', '6']], dtype='<U1')
```

If you want it as a string:

```
"".join(np.array(list(characters))[a].flat)
```

output:

```
'1AS8266'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_onehot_encoded(classes_array):
    # define universe of possible input values
    characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    
    return "".join([characters[c] for c in classes_array])

print(my_onehot_encoded([1, 11, 20]))
```

I got the following output:

```
1BK
```

Comment: I got a TypeError: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-0f648fdfb72f> in <module>()
----> 1 print(my_onehot_encoded(YOUR_RESULTING_ARRAY))

1 frames
<ipython-input-40-2ff0717b48df> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3     characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
      4 
----> 5     return "".join([characters[c] for c in classes_array])

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: You should call this function with the array that you received after image prediction, as I did in example. You can see that I passed an array of random class integers [1, 11, 20]. You should replace it with your array

Comment: Yes, I did this.

Comment: You might want to convert to casual* array first

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: wait a little, I'll try working it around

Comment: Glad you've got answered, have a good day!